# is there any error solving for javascript object to converting it into string

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core

[image]I am learning javascript where I get this error when I convert a object of js into a string it says semicolon required

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check a tutorial for the basic syntax.

There you are settings everything between `'` that can only be used for one line strings. That is probably not what you are trying to do.

If you really want a multiline string, you can use the backticks. Or you can have a normal object and use `JSON.stringify` to turn it into a string.

Comment: I got it thanks@Byruama

Answer (score 0):

When using single or double quotes, you can only do strings on one line, 2 possible solutions is using `JSON.Stringify` or backticks. Using backticks allows multiline strings and JSON.Stringify will convert everything to a string too!